# How to configure all subdomain so that it they returns server not found, not invalid certificate?

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server

I have only one subdomain configured, and it works properly. But if I request any other random subdomain `whatever.mydomain.com`, it returns an invalid certificate warning in the browser:

> This website may be impersonating "foobar.mydomain.com" to steal your personal or financial information. You should go back to the previous page.

How do I do disable all other subdomains so that instead they return server not found errors:

> Safari can't open the page "https://foobar.mydomain.com" because Safari can't find the server "foobar.twitter.com".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the wildcard DNS entry from your DNS records. Create records only for those subdomains which you intend to be accessible.